# How select all div class in all div except in one div

Tags: jquery, html, class, select

In my page i have a lot of div elements which have one o more div with the class `datos_variable_container`. I need to scan all those div with the class `datos_variable_container` but except in one div which name is `datos_resumen_atencion`.

How to do that ?

```
$('.datos_variable_container').each(function(){
});
```

I need something like this :

```
$('* .datos_variable_container').not('#datos_resumen_atencion .datos_variable_container').each(function() {
});
```

Comment: `.datos_variable_container:not([name="datos_resumen_atencion"])`

Comment: Do you mean `name` attribute? or `Id`. Because you used `#` in your selector

Comment: Thanks now it is working.

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways:

1. Using [`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

> Remove elements from the set of matched elements

```js
$('.block').not('#denied').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```css
.block { 
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="block">First</div>
<div class="block">Second</div>
<div class="block" id="denied">Third</div>
<div class="block">Fourth</div>
```

2. Using [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

> Selects all elements that do not match the given selector.

```js
$('.block:not(#denied)').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```css
.block { 
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="block">First</div>
<div class="block">Second</div>
<div class="block" id="denied">Third</div>
<div class="block">Fourth</div>
```